# Helm chart installation with Terraform time out issue

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I want to install Discourse with a helm chart via Terraform

```
resource "helm_release" "discourse" {
  name             = "discourse"
  namespace        = "discourse"
  create_namespace = true
  repository       = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart            = "discourse"

  version = "8.0.4"
}
```

and I takes quite some time during installation

```
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Creating...
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [2m0s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [2m10s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [2m20s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [2m30s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [2m40s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [2m50s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [3m0s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [3m10s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [3m20s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [3m30s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [3m40s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [3m50s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [4m0s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [4m10s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [4m20s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [4m30s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [4m40s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [4m50s elapsed]
module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0]: Still creating... [5m0s elapsed]
╷
│ Warning: Helm release "discourse" was created but has a failed status. Use the `helm` command to investigate the error, correct it, then run Terraform again.
│
│   with module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0],
│   on ../../modules/kubernetes_configuration/helm_general/main.tf line 314, in resource "helm_release" "discourse":
│  314: resource "helm_release" "discourse" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: timed out waiting for the condition
│
│   with module.helm_general_europe-west4.helm_release.discourse[0],
│   on ../../modules/kubernetes_configuration/helm_general/main.tf line 314, in resource "helm_release" "discourse":
│  314: resource "helm_release" "discourse" {
│
╵
```

However, after roughly 8 minutes everything is running, so it would be sufficient if the deployment steered by Terraform takes only 5 minutes.

Is there a way to fix that issue?

**Update:**

When I try this,

```
resource "helm_release" "discourse" {
  name             = "discourse"
  namespace        = "discourse"
  create_namespace = true
  repository       = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart            = "discourse"

  version = "8.0.4"

  timeouts {
    create = "10m"
  }
}
```

I get

```
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on ../../modules/kubernetes_configuration/helm_general/main.tf line 351, in resource "helm_release" "discourse":
│  351:   timeouts {
│
│ Blocks of type "timeouts" are not expected here.
```

Comment: Not sure if the `helm` provider supports timeouts, but you can maybe try this: https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/syntax#operation-timeouts.

Comment: @MarkoE Sadly. this issue comes up then: ``` Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on ../../modules/kubernetes_configuration/helm_general/main.tf line 351, in resource "helm_release" "discourse":
│  351:   timeouts {
│
│ Blocks of type "timeouts" are not expected here.
╵```

Comment: Sigh. There is also the `time_sleep` resource, not sure if that could help: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep

Comment: This will be a feature request for the Helm provider to support `timeout` meta-blocks.